# Validation while posting Journal Transactions AX 2009

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009

I wanted to make a field (salesTax) mandatory in Ledgerjournaltrans Table through code only for specific Company.

I have written the code in LedgerjournalCheckPost Class--> Checkjournal method(). Validation should be done while checking and posting the journal transactions.

The written code is never invoked. Can you please tell me what is going wrong. Thanks in Advance.

```
if(ledgerJournaltrans.AccountNum > '29999' || ledgerJournaltrans.OffsetAccount > '29999' && !ledgerJournaltrans.TaxGroup && ledgerJournaltrans.dataAreaId == 'EUR')
{
    allok = checkfailed('Tax Group is Mandatory');
}
```

Comment: Code is as below: 
if(ledgerJournaltrans.AccountNum > '29999' || ledgerJournaltrans.OffsetAccount > '29999' && !ledgerJournaltrans.TaxGroup && ledgerJournaltrans.dataAreaId == 'EUR')
            {
               allok = checkfailed('Tax Group is Mandatory');
            }

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint to see if the code gets to the `if` statement is even checked?

Comment: You may need to put your code in `postJournal`.